# Keeping a plot fixed as one parameter changes in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

In the following code I'm plotting the contour $f(x,y)=0$ as well as the family of lines $y=mx$:

```
Manipulate[Show[ContourPlot[f==0,{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5}],Plot[m*x,{x,-5,5}]],{{f,x^2+y^2-1}},{m,-5,5}]
```

The problem is: while changing the slope $m$ I don't want to re-render the contour, since it makes it look jagged for a short while. Is there a way to make some parameters affect only one of the plots?

Thanks!

Comment: For this specific case you can put `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` in the `ContourPlot`.  This will prevent slider movement from affecting the `ContourPlot`.  If you have two sliders and two plots, and you wanted the first slider to affect the quality of the first plot, but not the second, and you wanted the second slider to affect the quality of the second plot but not the first, then it would likely be quite a bit more complicated ...

Comment: @Szabolcs your comment resolves the issue, thanks!

Comment: @Szabolcs actually, could you please elaborate on how to get different controls to affect different plots?

Comment: I'll take a look tomorrow.  I don't know that off-hand.  I have to search the docs.  The keyword is `ControlActive`.  I'm not even 100% sure it's possible using documented functionality (though it likely is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managing `Manipulate` and other `Dynamic` functionality is tricky.  It takes some time reading the tutorials and experimenting to sort it all out.  (There are four tutorials linked on the [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) page that introduce you to the complicated issues of `Dynamic` and `Manipulate` that anyone interested in solving such issues needs to read.)  Even then you might still get surprised now and then.

The trick is to separate the code segments that need updating using [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html), [`Refresh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refresh.html), and sometimes [`DynamicWrapper`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicWrapper.html); further, one needs to control which symbols in each segment are being "tracked." [`Refresh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refresh.html) and the option [`TrackedSymbols`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackedSymbols.html) are sometimes needed for that.  When a symbol that is being tracked for a code segment changes, the code segment is re-executed (provided that the segment actually displays something in the front end).  Now, that's all very complicated, but in the OP's case, the solution turns out to be quite simple:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{cplot = ContourPlot[f == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]},
  Dynamic@Show[
    cplot,
    Plot[m*x, {x, -5, 5}]]
  ],
 {{f, x^2 + y^2 - 1}}, {m, -5, 5}]
```

The whole body of a `Manipulate` is always wrapped in `Dynamic`.  The `Dynamic@Show...` inside the `With` statement marks that segment as code that can be updated independently of the code outside.  When inside code is updated, *Mathematica* just uses the stored plot in `cplot` without recomputing `ContourPlot`.

When does the code get updated?  The inside `Dynamic` depends on `m`, but outside it, the `ContourPlot` does not.  *Mathematica* figures out that when `m` changes, only the inside code segment needs updating.  So when `m` changes, the line is replotted but the `ContourPlot` is not recomputed.  On the other hand, the `ContourPlot` depends on `f`, so the whole `With` statement will be recomputed whenever `f` changes.

As the OP noticed, when a slider is actively being adjusted, the `ContourPlot` gets jagged.  This is because by default `ContourPlot` and other plotting functions use [`ControlActive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ControlActive.html) to control the appearance of the plot when controls are "actively" being manipulated.  Basically, they reduce the number of points that need to be computed to speed the computation; this makes the app respond more quickly to changes in the control.  After manipulation of the control ceases, a new plot is computed with higher quality.  In the code above, when `m` is changed, the higher quality contour plot is already stored in `cplot`; it is this higher quality plot that is displayed while `m` is changed.  Not having to recompute the contour plot keeps the app responsive *and* gives you a good-looking plot.

---

**Alternative solutions**

**High, low resolution plots.**  From the comments, the OP seems interested in having a high-resolution contour plot.  The problem is that if the plot is too big (too many points and polygons), the front end becomes less responsive.   ***Can you make the demo responsive without reverting to the unsatisfactory default of `PerformanceGoal` switching between `"Quality"` and `"Speed"`?***

One way is to precompute both a high and low resolution plot as we did with `cplot` above.  One still has to balance quality and speed, and not every problem will be solvable.  But I've used this approach before.

```
Manipulate[
 With[{
   cplotHigh = ContourPlot[f, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4],
   cplotLow = ContourPlot[f, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 25, MaxRecursion -> 1]},
  Dynamic@ Show[ControlActive[cplotLow, cplotHigh], Plot[m*x, {x, -5, 5}]]],
 {{f, x^2 + y^2 - 1}},
 {m, -5, 5}]
```

**Rasterization.**
One can rasterize the contour plot, which will improve responsiveness.  It will look fine at screen resolution, but not if the magnification is changed or the graphic resized.  You can use [`Deploy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Deploy.html) to prevent resizing.  I suppose one could use [`CurrentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentValue.html) to get the magnification (perhaps `CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], Magnification]`).

```
Manipulate[
 With[{
   cplot0 = ContourPlot[f, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4]},
  With[{cplot = Rasterize[cplot0]},
   Dynamic@ Deploy@Plot[m*x, {x, -5, 5},
      Prolog -> {Inset[cplot]}, Axes -> False, Evaluate@Options[cplot0]]]],
 {{f, x^2 + y^2 - 1}}, {m, -5, 5}]
```

Note in both alternatives, the time to recompute when `f` is changed is increased.

Comment: Thanks Michael. There is still an issue that bothers me: If I modify your code to be more computationally heavy, such as
Manipulate[
 With[{cplot = 
    ContourPlot[f, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
     MaxRecursion -> 4]}, 
  Dynamic@Show[cplot, Plot[m*x, {x, -5, 5}]]], {{f, 
   x^2 + y^2 - 1}}, {m, -5, 5}]

then the reaction time for the slider is slower than in the simpler code. It seems that the cost of changing $m$ still depends slightly on the contour plot. Any insights on this?

Comment: Without `f` it's impossible to be sure. It could be the tooltips (turn off with `ContourLabels -> None`); see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58949. It takes time just to display `cplot` even if it is not recomputed. If `cplot` is a large amount of data (e.g. b/c of PlotPoints/MaxRecursion), then the time it takes could be noticeable. (Add `foo = cplot` inside the `Manipulate` and after it's computed once, execute `ByteCount[foo]` outside the `Manipulate` to check the size.) Maybe something about `f` causes `cplot` to be recomputed (you'd notice the jaggedness, though).

Comment: To be clear, I'm talking about the default f, namely $x^2+y^2-1$.

Comment: @user1337 Then it's probably the nearly 70,000 polygons in `cplot`.  I can see by monitoring the CPUs that the computational time is taken up by the front end, which does the rendering.

Comment: @user1337 I remembered a couple of other approaches, which I've added. Each has advantages and drawbacks.

Comment: Perhaps it should be a separate question but what is the solution to avoid the "jagged"-ness and force the computation of the full plot. I only have a parameteric plot and it takes very little time to compute the full correct plot after I release but it still shows the terrible jagged one initially. I'd rather have the update be a bit slower but show the correct figure. I tried `Block[{ControlActive=(#2&)}, ...]`, but it did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from szabolcs' dirty trick, a generic way to resolve this would be to precalculate one plot

```
g=ContourPlot[f==0,{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5}];
```

And then use manipulate with the precalculated plot

```
Manipulate[Show[g,Plot[m*x,{x,-5,5}]],{m,-5,5}]
```

Comment: But what if I want to manipulate on the function $f$ as well?

Comment: That's a good question